# Break content into multiple columns if needed, distribute elements from left to right

Tags: css

If we have some buttons like

[image]

and when the number of buttons increases so that a max height is reached, how do we get them in multiple columns like this?

[image]

and if the display becomes to narrow to accomodate for the columns (any number of columns that sooner or later are too wide) allow a higher "max height" like

[image]

## I tried this

```css
columns: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
```

Which results in button being distributed evenly between columns.

(The number of columns is also locked to 3).

If I set height of the parent, columns gets higher and possibly fewer (but I dont want the parent to have unnecessary height).

[image]

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `flex` with property  `flex-direction: column;`

```css
.container {
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
}
.item {
  background-color:black;
  height:30px;
  width:100px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  color:#fff
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

To change the height when many items I think you need `javaScript`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe there is no css only solution. I accept your answer to not have my question close voted even more. It is helpful regardless of the addition of javascript.